# Como insertar usuario guardado en variable de sesión

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, sesiones

comento mi inquietud:

Tengo un sistema con un login, una vez el se ingresa se cuenta con un formulario el cual captura unos datos y los inserta en una tabla de una base de datos mysql. Quisiera saber como incluir en ese insert, el dato del usuario que está realizando la operación (el que está logueado en el sistema).

**Código login:**

```html
 <?php
    include('controllers/conectardb.php');
    session_start();
    $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
    $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, "select DNI from usuario where DNI = '$user_check' ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $login_session = $row['DNI'];
    if (!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
       header("location:../index.php");
    }
```

**Código formulario:**

Agradezco de antemano la información que me puedan suministrar.

Comment: Deberás agregar un campo dentro de la tabla que se modifica, donde se guarde el ID del usuario logueado. Podrías ponerlo como ID_userMod. así después podrías saber que usuario fue el que hizo la modificación.

Comment: Ezequiel, buenas tardes, gracias por la respuesta. El asunto es que, efectivamente en la tabla donde se almacena la información del formulario, existe un campo destinado a guardar el 'ID_userMod', el asunto es que no se como guardarlo.

Comment: Cuando mandes la información que se captura en el formulario incluye también el ID del usuario logueado, ese ID seguramente esta almacenado en la variable de sesion. Debe ser algo asi como $_SESSION['id_user'], esto lo puedes poner en un elemento hidden de formulario te quedaria algo como... <input name="ID_userMod" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id_user']; ?>"> Ya en la pagina donde haces el INSERT agregas el dato del ID en tu sentencia de SQL.

Comment: Si pudieras poner el código del formulario de captura y la pagina que hace el INSERT seria mucho mejor explicarlo.

Comment: <form action="../models/2_mclientes.php" method="post">                  
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Primer nombre</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" name="nombre1" required="required">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="update ml-auto mr-auto">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-round">Registrar</button>
</div>
</div>
</form></div>

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta para que agregues el codigo y analizarlo.

Comment: @JCLXS perfecto, acabo de aplicar lo indicado y funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: De nada, me alegra que te haya servido. Saludos